# Csv file is not aligned correctly in excel

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel

I have a CSV file, when I open Excel then Add from File, I choose 'comma' as delimiter because it is like that, so when I see then the result it is not good.

Basically the "description" field contains "breaks / enters" and they are shown in new row although all that text is shown in " ", i don't know how to resolve this, anyone has any idea?

Regards

Here is the example of csv

```
ID,Type,SKU,Naam,Gepubliceerd,Uitgelicht?,"Zichtbaarheid in catalogus","Korte omschrijving",Beschrijving,"Startdatum actieprijs","Einddatum actieprijs","Btw status",Belastingklasse,"Op voorraad?",Voorraad,"Lage voorraad","Nabestellingen toestaan?","Wordt individueel verkocht?","Gewicht (kg)","Lengte (cm)","Breedte (cm)","Hoogte (cm)","Klantbeoordelingen toestaan?",Aankoopnotitie,Actieprijs,"Reguliere prijs",Categorieën,Tags,Verzendklasse,Afbeeldingen,Downloadlimiet,"Dagen vervaltijd download",Hoofd,"Gegroepeerde producten",Upsells,Cross-sells,"Externe URL","Knop tekst",Positie,"Naam eigenschap 1","Waarde eigenschap 1","Zichtbare eigenschap 1","Globale eigenschap 1"
341,simple,DM1R,"Title-DM1",1,0,visible,,"<h2>TITLE</h2>
<strong>this is only what i'm expecting</strong>


This is the csv file

Hey hey hey
Tralalal

Eén afmeting: 50 x 40
<em>*de afmetingen zijn in cm en hoogte x lengte.</em>
<h2>Some text!</h2>
more txt text text

Opmerkingen:
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2.</li>
</ul>",,,taxable,,1,32,5,1,0,,,,,1,,,32,"Diamond Paintings",,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,
```

Comment: I think you mean field `Beschrijving`, not `description`

Comment: Yes, that field is an issue .... it seems i don't know why it is split to another row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here when I import the given CSV as you describe on a Dutch machine. 
It seems Excel has a bug there.

What DOES work is to use a small piece of PowerShell to convert the delimiters in the CSV to the machine's default delimiter.
On a Dutch machine that would be the semi-colon `;`

```
# import the CSV with the comma as delimiter
$csv = Import-Csv -Path '<PATH-TO-THE-ORIGINAL-CSV-FILE>' -Delimiter ','
# export it again with a new name using either `-UseCulture` or `-Delimiter ';'`
$csv | Export-Csv -Path '<PATH-FOR-THE-OUTPUT-CSV-FILE>' -UseCulture -Force -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Next, you can simply double-click the new file and Excel will recognize the newlines inside the field.

Of course, you will still have to set the `Wrap text` option on the cell alignment afterwards. (In Dutch `Terugloop`)

[image: Cell alignment]

Hope that helps